# Update each selected datagridview rows

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for updating each datagridview selected rows but unfortunately it update only my first selected row.Why?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdo = new SqlCommand(@" update inventory set category = '"+textBox1.Text+"' WHERE id='" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
    cmdo.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in using first element of **datagrid** (*not item*) as ID in each iteration

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]
```

You should try this code:

```
int i = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdo = new SqlCommand(@" update inventory set category = '"+textBox1.Text+"' WHERE id='" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
    cmdo.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You mean (WHERE id='" + item.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con)??

Comment: I take this: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: It doesnt work. It updates first row e.x 3 times equal with the number of my selected rows

Comment: @user6453809 Then I would suggest you to add a counter variable just like woodykiddy added in his answer. Please check his answer. It will work perfectly!!

Comment: @user6453809 See my updated answer. Really sorry for taking your time

Comment: Oh nice to see it fixed! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like following

```
int rowIndex = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    con.Open();
SqlCommand cmdo = new SqlCommand(@" update inventory set category = '"+textBox1.Text+"' WHERE id='" + row[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
cmdo.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
}
```

All you need is a row index so you can use to iterate through. Also off the topic, it's not recommended to open/close database connection in the loop, as it would cause performance issues for large data set. You could consider using Bulk update or stored procedure.

Comment: Error 2 The name 'dataGridView' does not exist in the current context      Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'

Comment: Sorry just a typo in the sample code as I typed. Post updated for correction anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are always selecting first row 'SelectedRows[0]' . You need to iterate through each row with help of for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i< dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;i++)
{
//iterate through each row
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmdo = new SqlCommand(@" update inventory set category = '"+textBox1.Text+"' WHERE id='" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
cmdo.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
```

Please check this!

Comment: As i have corrected now please let me know if something wrong here!